What color is meant by "dove-colour(ed)"?
I stumbled upon the following in Stevenson's Vailima Letters (bold addd).

I was awake this morning about half-past four.  It was still night, but I made my fire, which is always a delightful employment, and read Lockhart’s ‘Scott’ until the day began to peep.  It was a beautiful and sober dawn, a dove-coloured dawn, insensibly brightening to gold.  I was looking at it some while over the down-hill profile of our eastern road, when I chanced to glance northward, and saw with extraordinary pleasure the sea lying outspread.

I'm wondering what color is referred to by "dove-colour". From the following brightening to gold, is it simply very-pale-yellow-ish white?
From what I googled a bit, the expression is not common. When 'dove-color' is used in English, is it expected to understand it as white? (I understand as a symbol of peace, dove is often depicted white; in reality, I see them very rarely or never.)

The color doves are most associated with in English is gray -- "dove gray."

4 here https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/dove

@StuartF: I have never thought of rock doves (i.e., pigeons) as being dove-colored. I think it's mourning doves that are. But then, I live in the U.S., and mourning doves are a New World species. I don't know what dove-coloured would mean in the U.K.

@PeterShor - It means the same (grey with a hint of pink).  Feral pigeons come in a variety of colours, but typically with a basis of light grey.

I guess I thought @Stuart's link was misleading, because it shows the picture of a pigeon that is much darker than the color I think of as dove gray.  Rock doves are a much darker gray than mourning doves. And the Cambridge dictionary, at least, agrees that dove grey is pale.

See pictures of dove gray.

Probably gray(ish).  Doves are most associated with the color gray, dove-gray being a light shade of gray.
The European turtle dove and common wood pigeon are both native wild species predominately gray.  Rock doves (also known as pigeons) tend to be gray, albeit typically somewhat darker than dove gray.
That all of these species are somewhat variegated in color lends the impression of clouds that are not uniform, as dawn clouds generally do vary in color.
And, of course, its connection with peace lends just a suggestion of a gentle and quiet scene.

From the OED:

dove-colour | dove-color noun
A warm grey with a tone of pink or purple.
Source: Oxford English Dictionary (login
required)

A dove is “a bird of the Columbidæ, or pigeon family.” Here’s one now:

Source: Wikimedia Commons
